# Setuptools how to build shared library before package installation

Tags: setuptools

My pacakge has *.py files and *.c files, the *.py files use ctypes to import shared library
built from the c source.

Now I have problem how to write my setup.py.

The setup script needs to build my_c_file.c to my_c_file.so, and then copy it to python libpath.

I want to know the what is the 'should' way?

Answer (score 3):

You should probably have a look at [Building C and C++ Extensions with distutils](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html).

If you build a setup.py file around the example below, setuptools should compile your c file into my_c_lib.so and automatically add it to your installed package (untested).

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

c_module = Extension('my_c_lib',
                sources = ['my_c_file.c'])

setup (name = 'my_package',
    version = '1.0',
    description = 'This is a package in which I compile a C library.',
    ext_modules = [c_module])
```

Comment: For others coming by in the future, this is _not_ what declaring an `Extension` does. A `Extension` will be compiled into a PYD file, which - technically - is a shared library, BUT it is expected to have a specific structure (export specific symbols). It is meant to be used directly in python, i.e., `from my_c_file import my_function; my_function()`. This is not what you are looking for when you want to use `ctypes` to call into arbitrary shared libraries.